# Error when saving suggested edit

Tags: discussion, bug, edits, suggested-edits

I have found this has happened on several occasions. Whilst making a suggested edit, if another user then edits the same post simultaneously, when I go to submit my changes, I get the error 'This Edit Would Have To Be a Suggested Edit';
which I have circled in yellow in the image provided.

[image: Suggested Edit Save Pane]

It's like my user id is mixed up with the other editor of higher rep. Is this a bug?

Comment: That just happened to me! Apparently the post was deleted then or soon afterwards; maybe that has something to do with it?

Comment: Yeh, It's happened a few times, and I'm not sure if it's always when someone else is editing it.. i'm now asking about 'bug' like things that occur reasonably frequently - I should be studying hey lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked the same [question](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/what-does-this-error-mean-this-edit-would-have-to-be-a-suggested-edit) the other day, and the [answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1512/11190) I got was that there was already a suggested edit in the queue. When you then go to submit your edit, the queue rejects it as there is already a suggestion pending.

It is a horrible error message, though. It doesn't accurately explain the actual error happening. It must be that the programmers lock a queue by removing the permission to edit the question in the same way that people with very low reputation points can't edit a question. I imagine you'd get the same error if you had a new user try to edit a question (if they could somehow bypass the missing 'edit' button).